# Xslt 1.0 check if something exists or empty value?

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0, string-utils

Hi I am wondering is there any function in XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0 to behave like java's Appache
**StringUtils.isBlank(String str)**

I use:
**Edited:**

```
<xsl:variable name="attributeNameValue" select="$sourceObject/attr[@name = $sourceName]" />   
<xsl:if test="$attributeNameValue and not($attributeNameValue='')">
   <!-- Do something-->
</xsl:if>
```

but I have this check over 100 in all my templates and wonder how to remove it with something faster?

Comment: What about `$attributeNameValue != ''`?

Comment: What kind of input are you facing? Textnodes only, Child-Nodes, Mixed-Content, Whitespace-Textnodes? If it's just a string, you can `<xsl:if test="not(string-length($attributeNamevalue))>`.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath/XSLT a common check is `not(normalize-space($foo))` to check that `$foo` is an empty string or a pure white space string.

Comment: But what about if it is null - N/A ?

Comment: What is a null value in your understanding in the XSLT/XPath 1.0 data model?

Comment: If the XPath can not find anything $sourceObject/attr[@name = $sourceName].
So this $sourceName do not exists where we are look for it.

Comment: `not(normalize-space($sourceObject/attr[@name = $sourceName]))` is true if an empty node set is selected by `$sourceObject/attr[@name = $sourceName]`.

Comment: what if we pass not Xpath but <xsl:variable> ??? and variable do not have value ? as in the edited example above? is it stil lvalid?

Comment: Given `<xsl:variable name="attributeNameValue" select="$sourceObject/attr[@name = $sourceName]" /> ` in XSLT 1.0, the value of the variable is of type node set and of course then the same applies, if the node set is empty then `not(normalize-space($attributeNameValue))` is true as in a string context an empty node set is converted to an empty string (<xsl:variable name="attributeNameValue" select="$sourceObject/attr[@name = $sourceName]" />), `normalize-space('')` of an empty string is still an empty string and `not('')` is true.

Comment: Ok I check this but it do the opposite thing if I try with boolean(normalize-space($sourceAttribute)) everything behaves as i expected.